# Calculating the interval and radius of convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence

I have $$s_n=\frac{-6^n(x+8)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$$  and I have to find the interval and radius of convergence.

Using ratio test:

$$\frac{-6^{n+1}(x+8)^{n+1}}{\sqrt{n+1}}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{n}}{-6^n(x+8)^n}$$

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}-6(x+8)\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}}$$

The last term goes to 1.

Since the interval must be smaller than 1, we get:

$$-6(x+8)<1$$

This gives $$x<-\frac{43}{6}$$, which should be the interval of convergence. Half of that again is the radius of converge, so $$x<-\frac{43}{12}$$

But this is wrong,

any ideas where the error lies and what the right solution is?

Thanks

Comment: 1) Do you mean $-6^n$ or $(-6)^n$? 2) The ratio test only applies to positive sequences (or to their absolute value), so the limit of the ratio (if any) is always $\ge0.$ 3) $-6(x+8)<1$ does *not* "give" $x<-\frac{43}6.$ 4) "[...]  the interval of convergence. Half of that again is the radius of converge" is gibberish.

Comment: @AnneBauval "The radius of convergence is half of the length of the interval of convergence. If the radius of convergence is R then the interval of convergence will include the open interval: (a − R, a + R). To find the radius of convergence, R, you use the Ratio Test." So it is not wrong to write "half of the interval is the radius".? With your answer it seems to me that the radius is 8, since the interval length is |-47/6-49/6|=16. So R.C.=8 ?

Comment: What I found incorrect was to confuse an inequation with its half-line of solutions, talk about half of this interval (i.e. half of this half-line: no idea what it is), and say that this *set* was a number ("the radius of converge"). As for the radius, it is not $8$. I shall add it to my answer. (You put a - instead of + in front of your 49/6.)

Comment: What is the exact formula for R? I got 1/3, by taking |UL-LL|/2, where UL and LL are the upper and lower limit respectively.

Comment: Of course, I forgot to divide by 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct typing for $s_n$ seems to be
$$s_n=\frac{(-6)^n(x+8)^n}{\sqrt n}.$$

Compute the same ratio test but for $|s_n|$ (not $s_n$ which takes negative values).

Eventually, you get that your series is *absolutely* convergent if
$$6|x+8|<1,$$
i.e.
$$x\in\left(-8-\frac16,-8+\frac16\right),$$
and trivially divergent if $x\notin\left[-8-\frac16,-8+\frac16\right].$

The radius of convergence $R$ is half the length of the interval of convergence $\left(-8-\frac16,-8+\frac16\right)$:$$R=\frac16.$$

If $x=-8-\frac16$, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty s_n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{\sqrt n}$ is divergent.

If $x=-8+\frac16$, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty s_n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt n}$ is a [conditionally convergent alternating series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series).

Comment: Thanks Anne, I will look at this closer tomorrow morning. Bonne nuit!